# How to disambiguate between the 'd' Standard and Custom format strings for .Net DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-formatting

In a .Net application, I would like to format a date and time in a fixed length format, but with no leading zeros for the day as below:

```
String.Format("{0:d MMM HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
"25 Jun 04:21:11"
```

This works for days of the month greater than ten, but (as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx)) does not insert a leading space. Now, the following should provide the format required:

```
String.Format("{0,2:d}", DateTime.Now);
"25/06/2016"
```

but, as is seen, formats the date instead using the standard [Short date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.100).aspx) format string. I can use:

```
String.Format("{0,2:''d} {0:MMM HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20));
" 5 Jun 04:21:11"
```

to get the desired effect, but this does not seem very satisfactory.
Is there less of a workaround to have the formatter use the Custom format string interpretation of an isolated `d` instead of the Short date Standard format?

Comment: Inserting a space before the date is an unusual thing to do...why would you expect a date format to support that?

Comment: Because numeric formats generally use the '#' character as a space holder for empty places in a format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To distinguish between a custom and standard format when the format is only a single character, use the `%` symbol.  For example: `{0:d}` gives the standard date format, but `{0:%d}` gives just the day of the month.  See [the MSDN docs for more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers).

So, you could do this:

```
String.Format("{0,2:%d} {0:MMM HH:mm:ss}", ...
```

However, consider that you could also just specify the length of the *entire* string:

```
String.Format("{0,15:d MMM HH:mm:ss}", ...
```

Of course, this assumes that `MMM` will always be three characters long.  That is true for English (as .NET uses "Sep" instead of "Sept"), but isn't guaranteed for all languages and locales.

Also note that you should use `HH` for 24 hour time.  `hh` gives 12 hour time, but is meaningless without using `tt` to indicate the meridem designation (am/pm).

Comment: I've updated the format to use 'HH' for correctness and appreciate you having found the documentation at the end of a very long page with the correct way to force use of the Custom format specifier.